# NavigationController interactivePopGestureRecognizer don't work when hidden

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, ios7, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using a NavigationController to display my View that inherit from MvxViewController. My NavigationController is hidden.

If I try to use back with gesture on iOS 7 as

```cs
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
...
    this.NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;
...
}
```

i have a NullPointer exception on InteractivePopGestureRecognizer

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

how could i simulate back without show navigation controller?

Comment: What exactly is NULL? The `NavigationController` or the `InteractivePopGestureRecognizer`? And would do you mean by "it's hidden"?

Comment: NavigationController hidden property it's set on true and null is InteractivePopGestureRecognizer. Thanks for help

Comment: `UINavigationController` does not have a `Hidden`property. Setting the controller's view to hidden is probably a bad idea if you want to use the controller. Can you provide a piece of code that shows in context what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry bar it's hidden `NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;`

Comment: No idea without further code, sorry.